# Running android studio project failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm having an issue trying to run a nativescript project.

It returns:

```
Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1. (Nothing else).
```

I've read all the posts related to this, but I'm not able to get a clear answer. I already cleaned the project, rebuilt the project, clear cache and restart Android Studio. But is not working.

Comment: Hard to know, but is it an emulator issue? If so try run a basic application and see if that works. If it does great its a code issue. If not its a setup issue.

Comment: I did not get relation with android studio and nativescript? When do you see this message_?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would want to run it on Android studio? You normally run a Nativescript project via tns command:    tns run android